# Add a self-signed SSL certificate to HttpURLConnection

Tags: android, ssl, httpurlconnection, self-signed

I know that there are some other questions on the same topic, however none of that questions are equals to my specific problem.

In my Android App I make Http requestes through `HttpURLConnection` to some RESTful end-points. Some of these end-points uses self-signed certificate, others no. So I need a way to add a custom KeyStore to the default HttpURLConnection behaviour.

This is the code I've now:

```
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(context);

            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);

            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "pasword".toCharArray());

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (KeyStoreException | IOException | CertificateException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnrecoverableKeyException | KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

It works, but only with self-signed certificates, any other request produce `java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

So, I'm looking for a way to let HttpURLConnection recognise custom self-signed certificates without destroy the normal behaviour.

Comment: Don't use the same file as both keystore and truststore.

Answer (score 4):

You have basically two options:

1. Accept any certificate regardless if it is signed by ignoring certificate validation
2. trust every certificate by adding all the certificates(even unsigned ones) to the keystore and load them with the same code as above and the exception should be gone.

Option 1, which I don't recommend, is creating a custom TrustManager which does not validate the certificate:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }
};

KeyStore keyStore = getKeyStore(context);

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, "pasword".toCharArray());

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), trustAllCerts, null);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

If the server does not require the client to authenticate, you can even drop the keymanagerfactory and initialize the ssl context with the following code:

```
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
        new X509ExtendedTrustManager() {
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, Socket socket) {}
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType, SSLEngine engine) {}
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) {}
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }
        }
};

SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, null);

HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
```

Comment: Or use for instance LetsEncrypt with a valid cert chain that the device already trust.

Comment: @Torxed That won't help if he can't changed the certificate of the servers/endpoints

Comment: I don't want to trust any certificate regardless its validity, it's a very dangerous way to get it working. The solution in my question works well, but the app is only able to recognize the self-signed certificate, but, for example, does not recognize as valid a LetsEncrypt certificate. So the question is how can I add a self-signed certificate to default SSLFacotry without loss the normal behavior? I hope I was clear

Comment: @Philip are you add this ssl certificate with TrustManager